# Setting up multiple whitelist using Candy Machine v2

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex, solana-cli, candy-machine

I am working to deploy my first minting site and wondering how I can go about setting up multiple whitelists. For example, I want to have 3 different whitelist each with a different price, where the first set of minters are on WL1 and can mint from 10am - 11am for 0.7sol, then starting at 11am WL2 can start minting at 0.8sol (and WL1 can continue minting at their whitelist price), and then at noon WL3 can start minting for 0.9sol along with the first two whitelists, and then finally the public mint would start at 1pm for 1sol..is this possible with Candy Machine V2?

I have seen a little bit online about using the endSettings in the config but I'm not exactly sure how that would work given each different whitelist would need to be associated with a different SPL-token I assume?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method to implement this with candy machine is doing multiple iterations of config changes.

e.g. first

```
  {
      "price": 0,
      "number": 6,
      "gatekeeper": null,
      "solTreasuryAccount": "5mktEkQdDh9hgh3nKLLM5B62vDvWwtums6LFLmK5Jujt",
      "splTokenAccount": null,
      "splToken": null,
      "goLiveDate": "21 Jan 2023 21:00:00 GMT",
      "endSettings": {
        "endSettingType": { "date":true },
        "value":"25 Dec 2022 10:00:00 GMT"
      },
      "whitelistMintSettings": {
        "mode" : { "burnEveryTime": true },
        "mint" : "7nE1GmnMmDKiycFkpHF7mKtxt356FQzVonZqBWsTWZNf",
        "presale" : true,
        "discountPrice" : 0.7
      },
        "hiddenSettings": null,
        "storage": "arweave",
        "ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
        "ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
        "awsS3Bucket": null,
        "noRetainAuthority": false,
        "noMutable": false
    }
```

then after 10 AM run update_candy_machine with a new config like this

```
  {
      "price": 0,
      "number": 6,
      "gatekeeper": null,
      "solTreasuryAccount": "5mktEkQdDh9hgh3nKLLM5B62vDvWwtums6LFLmK5Jujt",
      "splTokenAccount": null,
      "splToken": null,
      "goLiveDate": "21 Jan 2023 21:00:00 GMT",
      "endSettings": {
        "endSettingType": { "date":true },
        "value":"25 Dec 2022 10:00:00 GMT"
      },
      "whitelistMintSettings": {
        "mode" : { "burnEveryTime": true },
        "mint" : "7nE1GmnMmDKiycFkpHF7mKtxt356FQzVonZqBWsTWZNf",
        "presale" : true,
        "discountPrice" : 0.8
      },
        "hiddenSettings": null,
        "storage": "arweave",
        "ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
        "ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
        "awsS3Bucket": null,
        "noRetainAuthority": false,
        "noMutable": false
    }
```

etc.

It is NOT possible to have multiple WL prices etc. at the same time with candy machine.

Comment: OK if that is the only option then I would probably also make multiple different SPL-tokens and use a different one each hour along with updated price and then update candy machine so certain folks can only mint at particular times.